# Assigning property to subclass of RLMObject

Tags: realm

I'm trying to use a subclass of a RLMObject as a base class for a property of other subclass of RLMObject, with no luck. Is this a known restriction, or is there a workaround for it?

test.m:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface Base : RLMObject; @end
@interface Derived : Base; @end

@interface User : RLMObject
@property Base *obj;
@end

@implementation Base; @end
@implementation Derived; @end
@implementation User; @end

@interface rlmrlmTests : XCTestCase; @end
@implementation rlmrlmTests

- (void) testOK {
    User *user = [[User alloc] init];

    user.obj = [[Base alloc] init]; // OK
    [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] addObject:user];
    }];
}

- (void) testZFail {
    User *user = [[User alloc] init];

    user.obj = [[Derived alloc] init]; // ERROR
    [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
        [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] addObject:user];
    }];
}

@end
```

will get an exception saying:

> error: -[rlmrlmTests testZFail] : failed: caught "RLMException", "Can't set object of type 'Derived' to property of type 'Base'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a current limitation of Realm. It [doesn't support polymorphism](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/940) on relations.

If possible, I'd avoid inheritance in this case. You could reach that by altering your object-relational mapping: You could add a further *discriminator* column to your `Base` class and have relations to classes which contain further attributes and wouldn't inherit anymore from the `Base` class. If you have just one subclass, then a *discriminator* column is eventually not needed.

```
@interface Base : RLMObject
@property NSString *discriminator;
@property BaseExtensionA *extA;
@property BaseExtensionB *extB;
@end

@interface BaseExtensionA : RLMObject
// the properties of the prior `Derived` would go here
@end

@interface BaseExtensionB : RLMObject
// …
@end
```

Comment: Good to know that, thanks @marius. Though I could go the way you mentioned, extA and extB  should be listed in ignoredProperties. In my understanding, properties listed in ignoredProperties are not saved transiently in Realm when saving the RLMObject who has those properties...